# jquery copy a html element to a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can i copy a html element to a string correctly. I use metroui, version 4. They have a special input class where a X popsout with a click you can delete the value that you entered in the input.
https://metroui.org.ua/input.html

When i copy the html element to a var this X does nothing, but when i define a var with the string and append this, it works. When i get it with the element id, there is already injected the javascript code from metro js, because i use this data-role="input", then metroui js do some things. How can i get the same string as it would be with var div ? The pure html like it shows in editor? Or isnt this possible because jquery can only read the dom? So that i can read this pure html

```
        <span id="section-one-a1">
            <div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>
                <input value="val1" id="val1" type="text" data-role="input" />
        </span>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/css/metro-all.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>        
        $(function(){
            $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {

                var div = $('<span id="section-one-a1">'+
                '<div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>'+
                '<input value="val1" id="val1" type="text" data-role="input" />'+
                '</span>');
                //console.log(div);

                var newdiv = $('#section-one-a1').prop('outerHTML').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm,"");
                console.log(newdiv)

                var test = $(newdiv);

                $(div.appendTo("#p_scents"));

                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="main">
    <ul id="test">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="addScnt">new</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="p_scents">
        <span id="section-one-a1">
            <div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>
                <input value="val1" id="val1" type="text" data-role="input" />
        </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(newdiv)` output? What does `console.log($('#section-one-a1').length)` produce?

Comment: Outputs: `<span id="section-one-a1"><div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div><div class="input"><input value="val1" id="val1" type="text" data-role="input" data-role-input="true" class=""><div class="button-group"><button class="button input-clear-button" tabindex="-1" type="button"><span class="default-icon-cross"></span></button></div></div></span>` and 1

Comment: `<div>` (block-level element) inside a `<span>` (inline-level) ? nonono

Comment: I use this only for a selector at the moment. Has nothing todo with the problem. ;)

Comment: So what is the exact problem then? Your question says it did nothing. Yet you clearly have html result

Comment: The input field from Metroui have a X Button when you hover it and this Button does nothing when i copy from dom, but when i append it from string. I post a answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way no, perhaps not nicely, but works. Remove the elements and attributes that the MetroUI JS injected in the html when data-role is input, then it works. When it goes to the dom with appendto the metroui JS injected the new ones.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/css/metro-all.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>        
        $(function(){
            $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                var div1 = $('<span id="section-one-a1">'+
                '<div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>'+
                '<input value="val1" id="val1" type="text" data-role="input" />'+
                '</span>');
                //console.log(div);

                var newdiv = $('#section-one-a1').clone().html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm,""); // string
                var replace = newdiv.replace('<div class="input">',''); // replace input
                replace = replace.replace('data-role-input="true"',''); // replace data-role-input
                replace = '<span id="section-one-a1">'+replace+'</span>';
                var div = $(replace); // to object
                div.find(".button-group").remove(); // remove button-group
                //console.log(test)
                $(div.appendTo("#p_scents"));
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="main">
    <ul id="test">
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="addScnt">new</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="p_scents">
        <span id="section-one-a1">
            <div class="p_scnt" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">Test 1</div>
                <input value="val1" id="val1" type="text" data-role="input" />
        </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, small problem. When it have more then one input field, not working. Because the replace only replaces the first i think.